# Why does numpy's fromiter function require specifying the dtype when other array creation routines don't?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, generator, memory-efficient

In order to improve memory efficiency, I've been working on converting some of my code from lists to generators/iterators where I can. I've found a lot of instances of cases where I am just converting a list I've made to an `np.array` with the code pattern `np.array(some_list)`.

Notably, `some_list` is often a list comprehension that is iterating over a generator.

I was looking into `np.fromiter` to see if I could use the generator more directly (rather than having to first cast it into a list to then convert it into an numpy array), but I noticed that the `np.fromiter` function, unlike any other array creation routine that uses existing data requires specifying the `dtype`.

In most of my particular cases, I can make that work(mostly dealing with loglikelihoods so float64 will be fine), but it left me wondering why it was that this is only necessary for the `fromiter` array creator and not other array creators.

## First attempts at a guess:

### Memory preallocation?

What I understand is that if you know the `dtype` and the `count`, it allows preallocating memory to the resulting `np.array`, and that if you don't specify the optional `count` argument that it will "resize the output array on demand". But if you do not specify the count, it would seem that you should be able to infer the `dtype` on the fly in the same way that you can in a normal `np.array` call.

### Datatype recasting?

I could see this being useful for recasting data into new `dtype`s, but that would hold for other array creation routines as well, and would seem to merit placement as an optional but not required argument.

## A couple ways of restating the question

So why is it that you need to specify the `dtype` to use `np.fromiter`; or put another way what are the gains that result from specifying the `dtype` if the array is going to be resized on demand anyway?

A more subtle version of the same question that is more directly related to my problem:
I know many of the efficiency gains of `np.ndarray`s are lost when you're constantly resizing them, so what is gained from using `np.fromiter(generator,dtype=d)` over `np.fromiter([gen_elem for gen_elem in generator],dtype=d)` over `np.array([gen_elem for gen_elem in generator],dtype=d)`?

Comment: This link references the reason: http://sourceforge.net/p/numpy/mailman/message/13497603/

Comment: @toasteez This is great! But it actually doesn't seem to say anything about why `dtype` is required other than that Tim Hochberg who wrote it wanted wanted a 1d array with a specified `dtype`. Re: adding a shape parameter, they mention that they didn't want to make the code more complicated & that `array` has many complications…but that doesn't actually answer why `dtype` still is required for `fromiter` but not for _any_ other array creation routines. Also, the thread is almost decade old and numpy has changed a lot since then – so presumably changing it for API consistency was considered.

Comment: probably best to raise an issue / question on the numpy github,

Comment: a warning ... converting to numpy arrays will almost certainly not help your physical memory much because numpy arrays need contiguous memory blocks which are much harder to come by ...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If this code was written a decade ago, and there hasn't been pressure to change it, then the old reasons still apply.  Most people are happy using `np.array`.  `np.fromiter` is mainly used by people who are trying squeeze out some speed from iterative methods of generating values.

My impression is that `np.array`, the main alternative reads/processes the whole input, before deciding on the dtype (and other properties):

I can force a float return just by changing one element:

```
In [395]: np.array([0,1,2,3,4,5])
Out[395]: array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
In [396]: np.array([0,1,2,3,4,5,6.])
Out[396]: array([ 0.,  1.,  2.,  3.,  4.,  5.,  6.])
```

I don't use `fromiter` much, but my sense is that by requiring `dtype`, it can start converting the inputs to that type right from the start.  That could end up producing a faster iteration, though that needs time tests.

I know that the `np.array` generality comes at a certain time cost.  Often for small lists it is faster to use a list comprehension than to convert it to an array - even though array operations are fast.

Some time tests:

```
In [404]: timeit np.fromiter([0,1,2,3,4,5,6.],dtype=int)
100000 loops, best of 3: 3.35 µs per loop
In [405]: timeit np.fromiter([0,1,2,3,4,5,6.],dtype=float)
100000 loops, best of 3: 3.88 µs per loop
In [406]: timeit np.array([0,1,2,3,4,5,6.])
100000 loops, best of 3: 4.51 µs per loop
In [407]: timeit np.array([0,1,2,3,4,5,6])
100000 loops, best of 3: 3.93 µs per loop
```

The differences are small, but suggest my reasoning is correct.  Requiring `dtype` helps keep `fromiter` faster.  `count` does not make a difference in this small size.

Curiously, specifying a `dtype` for `np.array` slows it down.  It's as though it appends a `astype` call:

```
In [416]: timeit np.array([0,1,2,3,4,5,6],dtype=float)
100000 loops, best of 3: 6.52 µs per loop
In [417]: timeit np.array([0,1,2,3,4,5,6]).astype(float)
100000 loops, best of 3: 6.21 µs per loop
```

The differences between `np.array` and `np.fromiter` are more dramatic when I use `range(1000)` (Python3 generator version)

```
In [430]: timeit np.array(range(1000))
1000 loops, best of 3: 704 µs per loop
```

Actually, turning the range into a list is faster:

```
In [431]: timeit np.array(list(range(1000)))
1000 loops, best of 3: 196 µs per loop
```

but `fromiter` is still faster:

```
In [432]: timeit np.fromiter(range(1000),dtype=int)
10000 loops, best of 3: 87.6 µs per loop
```

It is faster to apply the `int` to `float` conversion on the whole array than to each element during the generation/iteration

```
In [434]: timeit np.fromiter(range(1000),dtype=int).astype(float)
10000 loops, best of 3: 106 µs per loop
In [435]: timeit np.fromiter(range(1000),dtype=float)
1000 loops, best of 3: 189 µs per loop
```

Note that the `astype` resizing operation is not that expensive, only some 20 µs.

============================

`array_fromiter(PyObject *NPY_UNUSED(ignored), PyObject *args, PyObject *keywds)` is defined in:

https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/eeba2cbfa4c56447e36aad6d97e323ecfbdade56/numpy/core/src/multiarray/multiarraymodule.c

It processes the `keywds` and calls
`PyArray_FromIter(PyObject *obj, PyArray_Descr *dtype, npy_intp count)`
in
https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/97c35365beda55c6dead8c50df785eb857f843f0/numpy/core/src/multiarray/ctors.c

This makes an initial array `ret` using the defined `dtype`:

```
ret = (PyArrayObject *)PyArray_NewFromDescr(&PyArray_Type, dtype, 1,
                                            &elcount, NULL,NULL, 0, NULL);
```

The `data` attribute of this array is grown with `50% overallocation => 0, 4, 8, 14, 23, 36, 56, 86 ...`, and shrunk to fit at the end.

The dtype of this array, `PyArray_DESCR(ret)`, apparently has a function that can take `value` (provided by the iterator `next`), convert it, and set it in the `data`.

```
`(PyArray_DESCR(ret)->f->setitem(value, item, ret)`
```

In other words, all the dtype conversion is done by the defined dtype.  The code would be lot more complicated if it decided 'on the fly' how to convert the `value` (and all previously allocated ones).  Most of the code in this function deals with allocating the `data` buffer.

I'll hold off on looking up `np.array`.  I'm sure it is much more complex.

Comment: Later I'll check some of these tests with the count specified (since the  length is determined on the fly by add 50% of the allocated array length each time it runs into the end of the array). The only issue I have is that old reasons for making dtype required were never actually given… your tests give a clue, but given that you can compute a partially ordered set on dtype representations(I think?), you would be able to infer it efficiently (working upward from `uint8`/`int8` to `object`, using C underpinnings of `astype` at reallocation time). But that would make `np.fromiter` really complex…

Comment: I found the `fromiter` code; it's quite simple.  `dtype` conversions are handled by the predefined `dtype` object.  `fromiter` just iterates, and keeps the `data` buffer large enough.